# Apps are starting firefox the wrong way

Tags: linux, firefox, hyperlink, links

I use Firefox as the web browser on a Debian (*) system. I had installed a recent firefox version manually, under `/opt`; used the `alternatives` mechanism to make that the default; then uninstalled it and removed that `alternatives` entry.

Now, however, I have a problem with web links in other applications, which are supposed to open a new tab or window in the browser: When I click such links, I get a message sayingDevuan ASCII

> Firefox is already running but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.

I'm assuming something is messed up with how Firefox is invoked (recalling that, for example, `/usr/bin/firefox` is just a wrapper script). What could it be? Where should I look? And how would I fix this?

<sub>* - It's Devuan ASCII, which is Debian Stretch sans systemd.</sub>

Comment: What is that 'alternatives mechanism'? Did you try to delete that Firefox script?

Comment: @Biswapriyo: 1. [The Debian Alternatives system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives). 2. No, it's distribution-provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of the newer Firefox version running when you press hyperlinks in other applications - even though they're "not supposed to" know about it.

Somehow, applications are congizant of the path of the manually-installed Firefox, and aren't just blindly going through the symlinks. So - they were still using what they knew to be a working firefox binary. I had to physically purge the `/opt/firefox-whatever` folder from the binary - and that worked.